# How to display pretty html in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to show html code on ui but i haven't found any library to format the html string

What i have is somthing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><title>Title</title><style>body {width: 500px;}</style>
<script type="application/javascript">function $init() {return true;}</script><body><p checked class="title" id='title'>Title</p><!-- here goes the rest of the page --></body>
```

I don't need it to be higlighted or styled i just want it to be more readable

Comment: I hope you were searching for something like this   [beautifier](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

Displaying the HTML codes directly in the browser is not recommendable as it can cause the "XSS Attack" issue. So what you can do is encode your HTML codes and put the encoded code inside "" tag in your HTML page.

you can use some tools like https://www.w3docs.com/tools/html-encoder/ to encode your HTML codes to display it in the browser. I hope this helps.